# How to handle events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I want to add class to this **li** with class `.nav-link`. I am using JS for it, but I don't know why this code is not functioning.
**P.s:** I am new to JavaScript

```
<script>
        const navLink = document.querySelector('.nav-link');

        navLink.addEventListener("click", reveal);
        
        function reveal(ev) {
            ev.classList.add("open");
        }

</script>
```

Comment: How do you check if the class list was added or not? Do expect a style change on click or something like that?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete snippet including the HTML?  Also, assuming you are using a modern browser to test this out, have you used the debug console to see if there are any errors?  For instance, if using Chrome on Windows or Linux, you can press Ctrl+Shift+I (or select More Tools > Developer Tools from the application menu)  to open the developer tools.  You should be able to see any errors in the Console tab.

Comment: Yes, I checked for errors in console, but there was none. I had put different style on the class which was to be added to check the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ev.target` to get that element.

```
<script>
        const navLink = document.querySelector('.nav-link');

        navLink.addEventListener("click", reveal);
        
        function reveal(ev) {
            ev.target.classList.add("open");  // <----------- Fix this line
        }

</script>
```